# The reputation that was ignored by accepted edits will be given back after I gained 2000 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

In [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238), it says "A maximum of +1000 reputation may be earned by users under 2000 rep. by accepted edits."

In this case:

1. I earned the equivalent of 2700 reputation, and 1800 of it earned by accepted edits. according this rule, this moment my reputation is (2700-1800)+1000=1900.
2. Then I earned 100 rep, and all of it is not earned by accepted edits, and my total rep achieved to 2000, so the rule should lose effectiveness to me.

The ignored rep by accepted edits will be given back? Will my rep be 2000 or 2800 now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The description there is misleading. I've gone and revised it, and I'll explain the confusion.

- You get +2 reputation per suggested edit, *period*. Your reputation at the time, and future reputation *does not matter*.
- You can gain a maximum of +1000 reputation from suggested edits, likewise period. Your reputation will never affect it.
- How much reputation you have does not affect your reputation gain from suggested edits, it affects *whether or not you can suggest an edit in the first place*. You need less than 2000 reputation to suggest post edits, and less than 20000 reputation to suggest tag wiki edits. Once you pass those thresholds, you no longer get reputation on account that you're just plain editing the posts/wikis now.

As such, no matter what, you're capped at +1000. Being over 2000 reputation only affects the ease at which you can try to reach that +1000 if you have not yet reached it.

Comment: In FAQ, it is said "5000 Vote to approve or reject suggested tag wiki edits ". and in this answer, you metioned "and less than 20000 reputation to suggest tag wiki edits.".How do you explain this difference?

Comment: @Roy Easily. You can approve tag wiki edits long before you can actually make then without suggesting them. It may *sound* weird, but that's how it goes. It basically forces a sort of peer review of sorts, where these 5000-20000 users have to double-check each other.

Answer (score 3):

You get rep for accepted edits as long as:

1. Your total rep is 2000 or lower.
2. Your total number of accepted rep is lower than 1000.

Both must be valid else you don't get any rep for accepted edits.

Comment: 1 is not true, you can suggest edits for tag wiki's